# Null objects in viewmodel

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm learning MVVM with databinding and I have problem with null objects in my TaskViewModel. I've created two constructors, and one of them is empty, but I have null in Task object. When I had only one constructor in viewmodel it made error with instance of viewmodel. What I'm doing wrong?
If you want more code please let me know.

TaskViewModel

```
public class TaskViewModel extends ViewModel {

private TaskRepository mTaskRepository;
private LiveData<List<Task>> taskMutableLiveData;
private String TAG = "TaskViewModel = ";
private Context context;

public final ObservableField<String> description = new ObservableField<>();
public final ObservableField<String> date = new ObservableField<>();
public final ObservableField<String> time = new ObservableField<>();


public TaskViewModel(TaskRepository taskRepository) {
  mTaskRepository = taskRepository;
}

public TaskViewModel() {
}

public void insert() {
    addTask(description.get(), date.get(), time.get());
    Log.d(TAG, "DATA " + description + " / " + date + " / " + time);
}

public void addTask(String description, String date, String time) {
    Task addTask = new Task(description, date, time);
    mTaskRepository.insert(addTask);
}
}
```

TaskRepository

```
public class TaskRepository {

private TaskDao taskDao;
private LiveData<List<Task>> allTasks;


public TaskRepository(Application application) {
    TaskDatabase database = TaskDatabase.getInstance(application);
    taskDao = database.taskDao();
    allTasks = taskDao.getAllTasks();
}

public void insert(Task task) {
    new InsertTaskAsyncTask(taskDao).execute(task);
}

public void update(Task task) {
    new UpdateTaskAsyncTask(taskDao).execute(task);
}

public void delete(Task task) {
    new DeleteTaskAsyncTask(taskDao).execute(task);
}

public LiveData<List<Task>> getAllTasks() {
    return allTasks;
}


private static class InsertTaskAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Task, Void, Void> 
{
    private TaskDao taskDao;

    private InsertTaskAsyncTask(TaskDao taskDao) {
        this.taskDao = taskDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Task... tasks) {
        taskDao.insert(tasks[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class DeleteTaskAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Task, Void, Void> 
{
    private TaskDao taskDao;

    private DeleteTaskAsyncTask(TaskDao taskDao) {
        this.taskDao = taskDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Task... tasks) {
        taskDao.delete(tasks[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class UpdateTaskAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Task, Void, Void> 
{
    private TaskDao taskDao;

    private UpdateTaskAsyncTask(TaskDao taskDao) {
        this.taskDao = taskDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Task... tasks) {
        taskDao.update(tasks[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You mean, your `TaskRepository` is null in `ViewModel` right?

Comment: I have this: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.daniellachacz.taskmvvm.model.data.TaskRepository.insert(com.example.daniellachacz.taskmvvm.model.Task)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making parameterized constructor for `ViewModel`, make your initialization in default constructor. because after all, we're consuming `ViewModel` from `ViewModelProviders` which has default constructor call from it *(if you haven't customized it yet).*

So do like below,

```
public class TaskViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private TaskRepository mTaskRepository;
    ...

    public TaskViewModel() {
        mTaskRepository = new TaskRepository(); // This will avoid your null pointer exception
    }

    public void insert() {
        addTask(description.get(), date.get(), time.get());
        Log.d(TAG, "DATA " + description + " / " + date + " / " + time);
    }

    public void addTask(String description, String date, String time) {
        Task addTask = new Task(description, date, time);
        mTaskRepository.insert(addTask);
    }
}
```

If you want to have `Context` in your `ViewModel`, use `AndroidViewModel` instead which will provide you **application context** in default constructor implementation. but don't store it in your `ViewModel` though.

Comment: But I have problem:
public TaskRepository(Application application) {
    TaskDatabase database = TaskDatabase.getInstance(application);
    taskDao = database.taskDao();
    allTasks = taskDao.getAllTasks();
}

As you can see I have there Application class and I have to use this in TaskViewModel constructor. When I'm using constructor in VieModel I have that error: ComponentInfo{com.example.daniellachacz.taskmvvm/com.example.daniellachacz.taskmvvm.view.TaskActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.daniellachacz.taskmvvm.viewmodel.TaskViewModel

Comment: I pasted constructor from TaskRepository. Comments under answers are terrible here :/

Comment: Ok it's fine now. I used **AndroidViewModel** instead **ViewModel** and **Application** class in constructor and it works. Thank you for help.